# How @Autowired applicationContext works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

What does Spring actually do when you autowire the applicationContext?

I first thought it does not appear in the applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames(), so I guess Spring injects any variable with autowired and ApplicationContext?

**Code example:**
Trying to get the injected bean:

```
@Component
public class Stackteste1 {

  @Autowired //Here it autowires the context without errors
  ApplicationContext context; //ps: i think it would be byType injection because no matter the variable name it injects

  @Bean
  public String testBean(){ //But if i try to get the context bean it says the bean was not found, the same happens in setter and contructor autowire
      context.getBean(ApplicationContext.class);
      return("test");
  } 

}
```

Comment: That is a [large topic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans.html) - can you update the question with a specific example with some code?

Comment: Isn't that covered by the Spring documentation? If not, what exactly is missing?

Comment: @Robert i think there's not any mention to injecting the applicationContext by autowire in the documentation, but i saw people doing this in many tutorials and forum answers

Comment: It is actually mentioned in the documentation, but in passing, see ["Customizing the Nature of a Bean", section "ApplicationContextAware and BeanNameAware"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/factory-nature.html#beans-factory-aware), specifically the paragraph starting with _"Autowiring is another alternative to obtain a reference to the `ApplicationContext`."_